# JavaScript await on async functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Simple question, lets pretend I have a function like this (In this example it's within a class, using an automation framework):

```
async logout() {
    await this.page.click('#logout');
}
```

and then call it in another file via

`await new LogoutPage(driver).logout()`

Do I really need the second `await`? Similarly if we return something with `await` IE:

```
async LoggedOut(): Promise<boolean> {
    return await isVisible('#logged_out_logo');
}
```

Would I need an `await` also when calling that?

Comment: If you don't use the second `await`, then you won't wait.

Comment: You would have to write `new LogoutPage(driver).logout().then(() => { code that runs after logout })`

Comment: Why are you using `async` and `await` in the `logout()` function in the first place? Does `click()` return a promise that you can wait for?

Comment: What happens when you try and test it?  You only *need* `await` (or a `.then()` callback) if you want to await the result of the asynchronous operation.  That's not always the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need the second `await`. See what happens when you remove the **first** `await`

```
async function LoggedOut(): Promise<boolean> {
    return isVisible('#logged_out_logo');
}
```

Then, you may the remove `async`

```
function LoggedOut(): Promise<boolean> {
    return isVisible('#logged_out_logo');
}
```

You see, the return type will remain `Promise<>`. async/await is pretty much syntactic sugar to avoid promises inside the function.

Thus, to the caller, that is still a promise which needs to be awaited...

```
await new LogoutPage(driver).logout()
// continue
```

or "thened"

```
new LogoutPage(driver).logout().then(() => {
  // continue
})
```

Comment: I guess im confused or maybe made the question not understandable. Why do we need an await calling the function if inside the function there is already an await

Comment: Because `await` inside is more or less syntactic sugar for a promise. Either way, `LoggedOut` function is async and returns a `Promise`. Because it is async, the caller still needs to await